Sending an email via Power Automate when specific items in SharePoint is edited
I have a SharePoint site which is used by other people as well. One of the columns consists of my name in it.
What I would like to do is that whenever an item which has a column with my name, is modified (when a specific column within the list with my name), I'd like to receive an email with the details of that item, e.g. all columns.
So far what I have tried is to use the "Get List" but I do not see the columns that are in the SharePoint site.
Has anyone tried this?

There is a SharePoint trigger in Power Automate called "When an item is created or modified". This trigger captures all the fields of the modified item. I believe that would be your starting point. So the structure of your flow might look something like this:

When an item is created or modified (SharePoint trigger)
Condition (check if the modified item has your name in whatever field you expect it in)
If true, Send an email (V2) (Outlook action)
If false, nothing

From there you would just need to add whatever fields and data you want to be notified of as dynamic content. For example,
Modified item title: triggerBody()?['Title']
This obviously has the downfall of triggering every time an item for your list is created/modified, regardless if it is one with your name in it. But as far as I am aware, this is the only SharePoint trigger that can kick off an automation for modifying items in a list.

other approach:

Create list view (can be a private one as well) which filters on your name
in PowerAutomate, in the trigger action (which should be 'When an item is created or modified') there is an option ('Advanced parameters' > 'Show all'): 'Limit Columns by View': this means, that the flow fires only if the new/modified Sharepoint list item would appear on this view.

